# QGraphicsView Zooming an Image to cursor when image is smaller than view

Tags: c++, image, qt, scroll, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to implement code that will zoom in an image as well as move the image towards the cursor, but not completely re-center on the cursor (similar to how Google Maps works, or exactly like how Picasa Photo Viewer used to work if anyone's seen that). The key is that it needs to zoom in the image, and have the same pixels that were under the mouse cursor, still be under it.

The sample code provided in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19114517/15812032) is close but does **not** completely solve the problem, as that was a question of moreso how to zoom in *with* the cursor and sidesteps the problem inherent in QGraphicsView.

The problem is: as seen in the sample code's comments in the header, it is not possible to perform this function if the view is bigger than the image. In other words, if you zoom out the image such that there's no scroll bars, then zoom in, the image will zoom in to the center, not to the mouse cursor; only by zooming in enough that there are horizontal *and* vertical scroll bars, will it zoom-in to the cursor and keep the same pixel underneath the cursor.

This seems to be a fundamental problem with QGraphicsView: QGraphicsView::setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse) can achieve almost the exact same result, but the Qt docs report the same problem:

> Note that the effect of this property is noticeable when only a part of the scene is visible (i.e., when there are scroll bars). Otherwise, if the whole scene fits in the view, QGraphicsScene uses the view alignment to position the scene in the view.

I suspect this is because both methods are *scrolling* the viewport, but if the image is too small compared to the viewport, there's no way to actually scroll it.

I suspect the solution may require abandoning scrolling and actually moving the image, but I can't figure out how to move the image such that the same pixel stays underneath the mouse cursor.

Here's some code that I've implemented and does not work:

Graphics_view_zoom.h:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsView>

/*!
 * This class adds ability to zoom QGraphicsView using mouse wheel. The point under cursor
 * remains motionless while it's possible.
 *
 * Note that it becomes not possible when the scene's
 * size is not large enough comparing to the viewport size. QGraphicsView centers the picture
 * when it's smaller than the view. And QGraphicsView's scrolls boundaries don't allow to
 * put any picture point at any viewport position.
 *
 * When the user starts scrolling, this class remembers original scene position and
 * keeps it until scrolling is completed. It's better than getting original scene position at
 * each scrolling step because that approach leads to position errors due to before-mentioned
 * positioning restrictions.
 *
 * When zommed using scroll, this class emits zoomed() signal.
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 *   new Graphics_view_zoom(view);
 *
 * The object will be deleted automatically when the view is deleted.
 *
 * You can set keyboard modifiers used for zooming using set_modified(). Zooming will be
 * performed only on exact match of modifiers combination. The default modifier is Ctrl.
 *
 * You can change zoom velocity by calling set_zoom_factor_base().
 * Zoom coefficient is calculated as zoom_factor_base^angle_delta
 * (see QWheelEvent::angleDelta).
 * The default zoom factor base is 1.0015.
 */
class Graphics_view_zoom : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Graphics_view_zoom(QGraphicsView* view);
  void gentle_zoom(double factor);
  void set_modifiers(Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers);
  void set_zoom_factor_base(double value);

private:
  QGraphicsView* _view;
  Qt::KeyboardModifiers _modifiers;
  double _zoom_factor_base;
  QPointF target_scene_pos, target_viewport_pos;
  bool eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event);

signals:
  void zoomed();
};
```

Graphics_view_zoom.cpp:

```
#include "Graphics_view_zoom.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <qmath.h>

Graphics_view_zoom::Graphics_view_zoom(QGraphicsView* view)
  : QObject(view), _view(view)
{
  _view->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
  _view->setMouseTracking(true);
  _modifiers = Qt::ControlModifier;
  _zoom_factor_base = 1.0015;
}

void Graphics_view_zoom::gentle_zoom(double factor) {
  _view->scale(factor, factor);
  _view->centerOn(target_scene_pos);
  QPointF delta_viewport_pos = target_viewport_pos - QPointF(_view->viewport()->width() / 2.0,
                                                             _view->viewport()->height() / 2.0);
  QPointF viewport_center = _view->mapFromScene(target_scene_pos) - delta_viewport_pos;
  _view->centerOn(_view->mapToScene(viewport_center.toPoint()));
  emit zoomed();
}

void Graphics_view_zoom::set_modifiers(Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers) {
  _modifiers = modifiers;

}

void Graphics_view_zoom::set_zoom_factor_base(double value) {
  _zoom_factor_base = value;
}

bool Graphics_view_zoom::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event) {
  if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove) {
    QMouseEvent* mouse_event = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
    QPointF delta = target_viewport_pos - mouse_event->pos();
    if (qAbs(delta.x()) > 5 || qAbs(delta.y()) > 5) {
      target_viewport_pos = mouse_event->pos();
      target_scene_pos = _view->mapToScene(mouse_event->pos());
    }
  } else if (event->type() == QEvent::Wheel) {
    QWheelEvent* wheel_event = static_cast<QWheelEvent*>(event);
    if (QApplication::keyboardModifiers() == _modifiers) {
      if (wheel_event->orientation() == Qt::Vertical) {
        double angle = wheel_event->angleDelta().y();
        double factor = qPow(_zoom_factor_base, angle);
        gentle_zoom(factor);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  Q_UNUSED(object)
  return false;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
};
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <Graphics_view_zoom.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setFixedSize(1000,1000);

    QGraphicsScene* s = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    QGraphicsView*  v = new QGraphicsView(this);
    Graphics_view_zoom* z = new Graphics_view_zoom(v);
    z->set_modifiers(Qt::NoModifier);

    v->setScene(s);
    v->setFixedSize(1000,1000);

    QPixmap pix;
    if(pix.load("C:\\full\\path\\to_an_image_file.jpg"))
    {
        s->addPixmap(pix);
    }
}
```

I've also tried the fix found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54018309/15812032) but this also has the exact same problem: the pixel will *only* remain under the cursor if the image is zoomed in far enough that there are both vertical and horizontal scroll options available.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hi! I included a link to the sample code from the other answer, but I've added it here too as actual code blocks, plus the UI-code that actually runs it, there shouldn't be anything left out. Thank you!